# Solve the congruence system

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

I'm asked to solve the following congruence system:

$$
\begin{split}
x      &\equiv 2 \pmod{5}\\
2x     &\equiv 1 \pmod{7}\\
3x + y &\equiv 4 \pmod{11}
\end{split}
$$

But I think that by the chinese remainder theorem, since $5,7$ and $11$ are prime, for any given $y$ the system will have a solution mod $385$. Doesn't this mean that the system will have 11 different solutions (mod $11$ for $y$ and mod $385$ for $x$)?

Comment: Check the Chinese Remainder Theorem. It states that this will have *exactly one* solution modulo $5 \cdot 7 \cdot 11 = 385$. And it's solution modulo $11$ will be $2$, as the problem states.

Comment: Yes, each system will have exactly one oslution modulo $385$, but what I mean is that since the system depends on $y$ each different $y$ will give a different system and thus a different solution. Isn't this true?

Comment: Sorry, overlooked that. Yes, for each possible value of $y$ modulo $11$ you get another $x$ modulo $385$. Just keep $y$ fixed, the CRT guarantees an unique solution for $x$.

Comment: Alright that's what I was asking since it seemed strange to me that an exercise would ask to find eleven different solutions. Thanks!